Anthology of stories about unicorns
The only story I recall is the ending of one story. The girl sacrifice is restrained. Her last realization is the unicorn means to kill her by stabbing her vulva with his horn.
Early to mid 2000s.
It was a hardback, US English book from the library. Unfortunately I can't remember cover, colors, etc.

It wasn't Unicorns! by Jack Dann/Gardner Dozois

I added a very few more details. Yes, that Dozois.

@user14111 - She, the sacrifice, is restrained.

There's also a Unicorns II by Dann/Dozois. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?52819

It's neither of the Unicorn books by Dann and Dozois. I reread both recently.

How about the gritty Immortal Unicorn (1995 and reprinted several times)? https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25985 There is also a second volume: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?159931

Tanith Lee's story The Hunting of Death: The Unicorn from Unicorns II has a similar scene where the sacrifice is stripped and tied down to await the unicorn. However it is not as explicit as you remember and the unicorn releases her in stead of killing her.

I've recently reread Unicorns! and Unicorns 2. So it's neither of those. Nor is it the Lore of the Unicorn, which turned out to be a scholarly work on the possible origins of the unicorn legends.

Will check out the Immortal Unicorn and get back to you.
